# How to cluster using just one feature

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am Trying to use kmean clustering for only one feature which is a number of devices and I have 360 samples and looking for 4 clusters. I tried this code below but not sure that the result is correct.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('/content/sample_data/FloorA_1.csv')
print("A) DATASET IS :" ,'\n', df)
df.describe()   #To make sure there are no missing values
import plotly.express as px
fig1 = px.scatter(df, x="devices")
fig1.update_layout(title="Feature Representation")
fig1.show()
```

Also Tried another code, but it does not let me to change the number of features to 1

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Make 4 random blobs in 2d space
X, y_true = make_blobs(n_samples=361, centers=3, n_features=2, cluster_std=0.5, random_state=0)
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], s=30);
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
kmeans.fit(X)
y_kmeans = kmeans.predict(X)
centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_

plt.suptitle("4 random groups of points - the cluster centers were found using the K-means algorithm")
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y_kmeans, s=30, cmap='jet')
plt.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1], c='blue', s=300, alpha=0.5);

print(X.shape)
print(centers)
print("---")
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLWqe.png]

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just need to know how to cluster using a dataset with only one feature. How to write the code when you do not have more than one feature?